# Add missing rows in a data frame containing multiple time series

Tags: r, time-series

I have a dataset containing sales data for first six months of 2012 (below is a sample)

```
   month=c('2012-M01','2012-M02','2012-M04','2012-M05','2012-M06',
   '2012-M01','2012-M02','2012-M03','2012-M04','2012-M05','2012-M06',
   '2012-M02','2012-M03','2012-M05','2012-M06')
   product=c('A','A','A','A','A','B','B','B','B','B','B','C','C','C','C')
   sales=c(10,5,10,5,10,10,20,30,40,50,60,20,10,5,5)
   df = data.frame(month, product, sales)
```

I want to do the following: 
1) for each product, fill the missing month with 0 sales. That is, to produce a data frame that has the following contents:

```
  month=c('2012-M01','2012-M02',**'2012-M03'**,'2012-M04','2012-M05','2012-M06',
    '2012-M01','2012-M02','2012-M03','2012-M04','2012-M05','2012-M06',
    '2012-M02','2012-M03',**'2012-M04'**,'2012-M05','2012-M06')
  product=c('A','A','**A**','A','A','A',B','B','B','B','B','B','C','C',**'C'**,'C','C')
  sales=c(10,5,**0**,10,5,10,10,20,30,40,50,60,20,10,**0**,5,5)
  df = data.frame(month, product, sales)
```

Notice that for product A, a row containing sales 0 for 2012-M03 is added; for product C, a row containing sales 0 for 2012-M04 is added. For product B, no row is added. Also note that for product C, I don't want to add a row saying sales is 0 for M01; this is because we only start selling product C in M02.

2) convert the sales of each products into a time series (i.e., a total of three time series), but, still carry all the information in a single data frame.

Please let me know how to achieve 1) and 2) above. Thanks in advance!

Comment: You should produce a dataframe that has the constraints in some form. Since there are at least two different data structures that could be called "time series" you should also say exactly what you mean by the use of that term.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this very easily with the reshape2 package!

```
 #if you don't have it yet
 install.packages("reshape2")

 library("reshape2")

 #your setup 
 month=c('2012-M01','2012-M02','2012-M04','2012-M05','2012-M06',
'2012-M01','2012-M02','2012-M03','2012-M04','2012-M05','2012-M06',
'2012-M02','2012-M03','2012-M05','2012-M06')

product=c('A','A','A','A','A','B','B','B','B','B','B','C','C','C','C')

sales=c(10,5,10,5,10,10,20,30,40,50,60,20,10,5,5)

df = data.frame(month, product, sales)

# my stuff
df.melted = melt(df, id = c("month", "product"))

df.new = dcast(df.melted, month ~ product)

noleadingNAs = apply(df.new, 2, function(x) {
      y = x[match(TRUE,!is.na(x)):length(x)]
     }
   )


noNAs= lapply(noleadingNAs, function(x) {
    x[is.na(x)] = 0
    return(x)
   }
 )

totlen = max(sapply(noNAs, length))

balanced.df = as.data.frame(lapply(noNAs, function(x){
if(length(x) < totlen){
   x=c(rep(NA,totlen - length(x)),x)
 }
 else{x}
 }
 ), stringsAsFactors=FALSE
 )

data.m.wna = melt(balanced.df, id = "month")

data.final = data.m.wna[!is.na(data.m.wna$value),]
```

Hope that helps.

Edit: I can't say that it's pretty but I've edited my answer to drop leading NAs. There may be a better way but this will work.

Comment: Thanks! I tried this and it works well, except for one thing--in my dataset, product C starts selling in 2012-M02. I want to keep the way it is, as opposed to creating a row specifying product C sales is zero for 2012-M01. In another word, for each product, I want to fill missing values only for the period that this product is sold. Could you please advise how to modify the code? Thanks.

Comment: Sorry for the later reply. Just tried and it works well; thanks very much!